# Evaluating definite integral of a function

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

f(x) is a function which satisfies 
$$ f(x) = f(\frac {100}{x}). $$ 
For all real and positive x.

Its given that 
$$ \int_{1}^{10} \frac {f(x)}{x} dx = 5 $$ 
then how to evaluate
$$\int_{1}^{100} \frac {f(x)}{x} dx $$

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$$\begin{align}\int_1^{100} dx \frac{f(x)}{x} = \int_1^{10} dx \frac{f(x)}{x} + \int_{10}^{100} dx \frac{f(x)}{x} \end{align}$$

and sub $x=100/u$ in the 2nd integral.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose more generally that $a>0$ and
$$ f(x)=f(a^2/x). $$
Then we need to look at
$$ \int_a^{a^2} \frac{f(x)}{x} \, dx = \int_a^{a^2} \frac{f(a^2/x)}{x} \, dx. $$
Use the substitution $y=a^2/x$: then $x=a \implies y=a$, $x=a^2 \implies y=1$, and $dx/x=-dy/y$, so
$$ \int_a^{a^2} \frac{f(a^2/x)}{x} \, dx = \int_1^a \frac{f(y)}{y} \, dy, $$
and so
$$ \int_1^{a^2} \frac{f(x)}{x} \, dx = 2\int_1^a \frac{f(x)}{x} \, dx. $$